# Scala junit picking up wrong log4j.properties file

Tags: scala, logging, junit, log4j

I have a test written in Scala, using junit. The test is in a module of a  multi-pom with many other modules.

Here is the code of the test:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.logging.log4j.scala.Logging
import org.junit._


class MyTest extends Logging {

  @Test
  def mainTest() = { 
    //val logger = Logger.getLogger("MyTest")

    logger.fatal("fatal")
    logger.error("error")
    logger.warn("warn")
    logger.info("info")
    logger.debug("debug")
    logger.trace("trace")
  }
}
```

And here is the log4j.properties file, which is in the `resources` folder:

```
log4j.rootCategory=ALL, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
```

The maven dependencies are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api-scala_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I run the test, the `debug` and `trace` levels are not printed.

It seems to me that the logger might be picking up a files from one of the other projects. why?

If I uncomment the first line of the test, all the levels get printed.

Tried adding `-Dlog4j.debug` to the run command, but log4j seems to be ignoring it.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Where is your `log4j.properties` located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using log4j2.

Your file name should be `log4j2.properties`.

Also, the syntax of the `.properties` file has changes. The following example, taken from [here](https://springframework.guru/log4j-2-configuration-using-properties-file/), will get you started:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/propertieslogs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name=guru.springframework.blog.log4j2properties
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```